# ASP.NET Saving Data

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, entity-framework

So I have a basic crud that displays information on ASP.Net using entity framework. When i click details it shows the information for that row on a table. I've input a button and a label that when is clicked shows a number, when clicked again it will show the next number higher. It's basically to just a button counter written with JQuery. My question is, is there a way to save this number? I want to store the data in the program so it doesn't forget the number when I move to a different page.

Here is the JQuery.

```
var count = 0;
function Count() {
    count++;
    $('#lblShow').text(count);

}
<div>
    <input type="submit" name="btnCount" value="Add Signature" onclick="return Count();" id="btnCount" />  <input type="submit" name="btnCountSoc" value="Post to Social Media" id="btnMedia" />
    <span id="lblShow"></span>
</div>
```

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `cookie` have for this. Can you try?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies like :

```
var counter = $("#foo").val();
document.cookie = "counter="+counter";path=/";
```

Comment: Yeah i'm not really sure how to add this to make it work.

Comment: add this one to your function to work